# Making point selection tool using ArcObjects with VBA?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vba, select

I want to make a selection tool that I can use to select a feature point in ArcGIS for Desktop so I can combine it with a form that I just made to display the form after the feature selected.

I use VBA but, because I'm newbie, I don't really understand which interface that I should use.